# Changing camera direction without affecting its location

Tags: opengl, camera, rotation

I'm changing the camera location and direction According to mouse movement and buttons pressed.

In order to move the camera 5 units forward(for example) according to its direction, I'm using the following code:

```
float mview[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mview);
translate_forward_camera += 5; //I have translate_right_camera and 
                               //translate_up_camera variables too
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0, 0, 5);
glMultMatrixf(mview);
```

Same with moving to the sides.

However, I have not idea how to change the direction of the camera without changing its location. I am rotating the camera around itself at (0,0,0).
The previous *y* , *x* rotation angles are:

```
old_x_ang, old_y_ang
```

The new *y* , *x* rotation angles (I need to rotate the camera at (0,0,0) using this angles)
 are:

```
x_ang, y_ang
```

If I'll use the following code, the camera location will change:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(translate_right_camera,translate_up_camera,translate_forward_camera);
glRotatef(x_ang,1,0,0);
glRotatef(y_ang,0,1,0);
```

How can one rotate the camera without changing its location?

Answer (score 1):

In the typical case, a view matrix can be decomposed intwo two separate transformations:

- a translation T defining the camera postion, and
- a rotation R defining the camera orientation

You might have learned from object placement in world space, that you typically roate first (around the object's origin), and than translate the object to the final position on world space. Due to the fact the fixed-function GL transformation uses the matrix * colum-vector convention, you had to define the operation as T * R to get the effect of rotating first and then translating.

And that has been what you are doing here. And it does not work. The reason is that the view matrix does not place the camera in the world, but is part of the vertex transformation to transfrom the vertices from world space to view space - hence the view matrix is the *inverse* of that. And generally for matrices you get (A*B)^-1 = B^-1 * A^-1.

So what this means is that the T in our case is the inverse of the camera world position, and R the inverse rotations, and you have to apply R * T. This also makes total sense since T transforms the vertices into view space, where the origin is the camera position, and you then rotate around that local origin to rotate the camera without changing its position. So all you have to do is swithcing that `glTranslate()` call to the end if the transformation sequence.

I generally would recommend that you stop using the GL matrix stack, not only because it is deprecated and not available in modern GL, but also because it is very inefficient to read the matrix back from the GL.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate first, then translate. Generally you want to scale first, then rotate, then translate -- *in reverse order*. It would **usually** look like this for a ModelViewProjection matrix:

```
MVP = ProjectionViewMatrix * translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * scaleMatrix;
```